# Can you make a module visible in an Ember unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

My boss says we should use a unit test. I have to test the functionality of a calendar module with click functions, is it possible to make a module visible in a unit test so I can run click() methods on it to test features or are unit tests always invisible in Ember?

I've tried making a unit test with similar syntax to an integration test but it doesn't work. I need to see the module to run click methods on it to test basic functionality, is this possible?

```
module('Unit | Mixin | eg picker/calendar single')

test('it works', function (assert) {
let EgPickerCalendarSingleObject = 
EmberObject.extend(EgPickerCalendarSingle);
let subject = EgPickerCalendarSingleObject.create();
assert.ok(subject);
});
```

Comment: you want acceptance testing for user interactions. "Unit testing" is for non-ui things.

Comment: That's what I thought, he insists it's possible to view ui things in a unit test via breakpoints and that click() can be used.

Comment: what he thinks is unit testing is not unit testing. :-\
sorry, but you must either do acceptance or integration testing in order to test ui.
I recommend starting with acceptance tests, because you get access to all the ui testing helpers, and it allows you to more easily reason about what is happening in your app. Integration tests are then for when you have a complicated component that you want to ensure has predictable behavior given whatever complicated set of inputs.
Unit tests do not touch the ui.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was pretty sure what you said is true, we got ransomwared today so he probably was just flustered and I didn't want to press him on it. I'll start making acceptance tests and see how that goes over.

Comment: acceptance tests are beautiful. :)

they make sure you're going through actual user flows

Comment: Confirm what nullvox said, unit tests are not able to do ui and clicking.

Answer (score 2):

The vocabulary around testing is different for different languages and frameworks. I would consider Ember's integration tests to be the same as what a PHP developer would call a behavioral unit test whereas what a Java developer calls and integration test isn't even part of the Ember ecosystem.

Your boss isn't wrong, unit tests are usually the best way to test small isolated interactions, we just call them integration tests in Ember.

Source: been doing TDD for a long time across many languages, jobs, and frameworks.